# split but keep the separator for few

Tags: awk, split

I am having a large file which column one is in the following format. There can be 3-6 different id separated by "_"

```
s1_asd_ucsd
b4_asd_id_vu
c10_id_js_uw
d4_sch_vu
```

I want to split this column into two column. Column 2 contain the last id and column 1 contain the initial ids; like bellow

```
s1_asd  ucsd
b4_asd_id   vu
c10_id_js   uw
d4_sch  vu
```

I know how to print the last column by following; but dont know how to print the previous ids while keeping the separator.

```
awk '{n=split($1, b, "_"); }{  print b[n]}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*_/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Simple explanation would be: Using `match` function of `awk` to match till last occurrence of `_` in each line and then while printing its sub strings printing just before last `_` to remove it and then printing rest of the line(along with space between matched part and rest part).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {last=$NF; NF--; print $0 "   " last}' file
```

Save last field, remove last field from current row, output current row, output three spaces and append saved last field.

Output:

```
s1_asd   ucsd
b4_asd_id   vu
c10_id_js   uw
d4_sch   vu
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: My files are from patient sample collected at multiple location so some time there will be multiple columns and the 1st column is the one one which I need to split. I think FS=OFS="_" will not work for such files.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `sed` solution using greedy matching pattern:

```sh
sed -E 's/(.+)_(.+)/\1   \2/' file

s1_asd    ucsd
b4_asd_id    vu
c10_id_js    uw
d4_sch    vu
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Can I use this to work when I have multiple column and  1st column is the one which I wanted to split?

Comment: Yes definitely this command can be tweaked for such requirement as well using `sed -E 's/^([^_]+)_(.+)/\1   \2/' file`